# How to pass extra information to request handler instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, socketserver

Is there a standard way to make extra information available to handlers from the `socketserver` module? The following is about the simplest solution I could think of, but it is unconvincing that this is the best way to make sure that handlers get access to some resources that they can all share.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import socketserver


def main():
    address = 'localhost', 10000
    history = [b'Hello, world!']
    server = CustomUDPServer(address, UDPHandler, history)
    server.serve_forever()


class CustomUDPServer(socketserver.UDPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, history):
        super().__init__(server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
        self.history = history


class UDPHandler(socketserver.DatagramRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.wfile.write(self.server.history[-1])
        self.server.history.append(self.rfile.read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```